# Moving Excel Sheets From Workbook to Another Using SSIS

Tags: c#, excel, ssis, etl, script-task

I have code that is supposed to move a excel template sheet into a new work book (See below)

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

namespace CodeCall
{
    public class Excel
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            ApplicationClass app = new ApplicationClass();
            Workbook curWorkBook = null;
            Workbook destWorkbook = null;
            Worksheet workSheet = null;
            Worksheet newWorksheet = null;
            Object defaultArg = Type.Missing;
            try
            {
                // Copy the source sheet
                curWorkBook = app.Workbooks.Open("filepath1", defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
                workSheet = (Worksheet)curWorkBook.Sheets[1];
                workSheet.UsedRange.Copy(defaultArg);

                // Paste on destination sheet
                destWorkbook = app.Workbooks.Open("filepath2", defaultArg, false, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
                newWorksheet = (Worksheet)destWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(defaultArg, defaultArg, 6, defaultArg);
                newWorksheet.UsedRange._PasteSpecial(XlPasteType.xlPasteValues, XlPasteSpecialOperation.xlPasteSpecialOperationNone, false, false);
            }
            catch (Exception exc)
            {
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(exc.Message);
            }
            finally
            {
                if (curWorkBook != null)
                {
                    curWorkBook.Save();
                    curWorkBook.Close(defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
                }

                if (destWorkbook != null)
                {
                    destWorkbook.Save();
                    destWorkbook.Close(defaultArg, defaultArg, defaultArg);
                }
            }
            app.Quit();
        }
    }
}
```

When I run the code, I get this error message:

> Error: Cannot load script for execution.

I've already tried copying and pasting my script code into a new task.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve it.

1. I needed to add the Script entry point to the code

   ```
   [SSISScriptTaskEntryPoint]//Attribute]

   public partial class ScriptMain : VSTARTScriptObjectModelBase
   ```
2. Remove the "Excel" public class

Taking the code from "Public Static Void Main()", pasting it into a new Script Task template and updating the namespaces accordingly fixed it.